# Using a unique_ptr to manage a three dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, unique-ptr

I have assigned a three dimensional using the following way:

```
board = new char**[depth];
    for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++)
    {
        board[d] = new char*[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            board[d][i] = new char[cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                board[d][i][j] = 'k';
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to use a unique_ptr to manage it, but I don't know how to initiate such a structure using the interface that unique_ptr exposes.

Comment: Don't use `std::unique_ptr` for this, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @SergeyA what do you mean? I am assigning a 3-dimensional array. How can I use a vector for that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have different dimensions of each row/column?
Otherwise, you could just allocate `depth*rows*cols` in one shot.

Comment: There are no 3-dimensional arrays in C or C++. What you have is an array of arrays of arrays. The same can be done with vectors of vectors of vectors.

Comment: @erenon yes the dimensions are different

Comment: @primeQuestion: in your example, they are not.

Comment: I would suggest using a single allocation, your code will be a lot simpler all things considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ostensibly, you could write it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<char[]>[]>[]>board = 
    std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<char[]>[]>[]>(depth);
for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++)
{
    board[d] = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<char[]>[]>(rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        board[d][i] = std::make_unique<char[]>(cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            board[d][i][j] = 'k';
        }
    }
}
```

And this will more-or-less work the way you expect.

But **Holy Spaghetti Code, Batman!** That is some seriously sloppy code!

You could simplify it like this using `std::vector` which is a far more natural construct for representing arrays-of-arrays-of-arrays:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<char>>> board;
board.resize(depth);
for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++)
{
    board[d].resize(rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        board[d][i].resize(cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            board[d][i][j] = 'k';
        }
    }
}
```

But given that you're writing what is essentially a 3D Rectangular Matrix, it still doesn't make much sense to write it like this. Instead, let's do this:

```
size_t get_index(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t depth) {
    if(i > rows || j > cols || k > depth) throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds!");
    return k * rows * cols + j * rows + i;
}

size_t get_size(size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t depth) {
    return rows * cols * depth;
}

int main() {
    size_t rows = 15, cols = 10; depth = 5;
    std::vector<char> board(get_size(rows, cols, depth));
    for(size_t d = 0; d < depth; d++) {
        for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                board[get_index(r, c, d, rows, cols, depth)] = 'k';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You might consider wrapping all of this up into a `Matrix` class which handles all this translation on its own. Then you'd be able to write code that looks like this:

```
int main() {
    size_t rows = 15, cols = 10; depth = 5;

    Matrix<char> board(rows, cols, depth);
    for(size_t d = 0; d < board.get_depth(); d++) {
        for(size_t r = 0; r < board.get_rows(); r++) {
            for(size_t c = 0; c < board.get_cols(); c++) {
                board(r, c, d) = 'k';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which is far cleaner, far easier to maintain, and if you make your `Matrix` class generic, reusable for other things.